# How to add an image in shell header on a freestyle portal site?

Tags: sapui5, portal, sap-cloud-platform

I need to add an image on the header of a freestyle portal site which when clicked should open a new window with a specific URL.
Currently tried adding the below code but it appears very small, just like a profile picture. But our requirement is to make it appear more like a logo and on the right side (as an header end item).

```
var oImageItem = new sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeadItem("imageId", {
                    icon: "/images/image1.png",
                    tooltip: "Click here",
                    //height: "100%",
                    showSeparator: false,
                    href: "HarcodeURL",
                    target: "_blank"

                });
                oRendererExtensions.addHeaderEndItem(oImageItem);
```

Comment: You must use custom icons, and place your picture inside the custom icon. Here are two useful links on how add custom icons: [link1](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7b390faab1140c087b8926571e942b7/7.51.9/en-US/3e4ba0dbef874eb5a6bc88bb9f0787e5.html), [link2](https://answers.sap.com/questions/365783/how-to-add-the-menu-button-in-shellheaditem.html)

Answer (score 1):

This link could be very interesting: [How to place logo or icon at the Center of Unified Shell header?](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3906303)

You have to change "Center" to "Right" and "Icon" to "Image"

That would look like this:

```
var oShell = new sap.ui.unified.Shell("oShell", {
   header: [
     new sap.m.FlexBox({
       justifyContent: sap.m.FlexJustifyContent.Center,
       items: [
         new sap.ui.core.Icon({
           src: "sap-icon://home"
         })
       ]
     })
   ]
});
```

You also could change the "FlexBox" to a "VBox".

Answer (score 0):

This element doesn't exist. Use the "sap.m.Image" element. ([SDK sap.m.Image](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Image))

Code with XML: `<m:Image src="/images/image1.png" width="100px" press="openNewWindow">`

Code with JS:

```
var oImageItem = new sap.m.Image("imageId", {
                src: "/images/image1.png",
                tooltip: "Click here",
                width: "100px",
                press="openNewWindow"
            });
```

Press Event in Controller:

`openNewWindow: function(){
            window.open("https://www.hypej.com");
        },`

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing, how we can add an image in the site header using a shell plugin. As far as I know, we can only add Icon on headers through some pre-defined code.